# 301 redirect for individual pages .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

I have tried various ways to write the .htaccess file but all i get is a 500 server error.

I am trying to redirect all the pages from one website to another.  This is because the website has been rewritten and has had a change of name.  I want to keep all the seo intact.

I have put the .htaccess file in the root directory and here is a copy

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{http_host} ^yachting-school.co.uk [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.yachting-school.co.uk/$1 [R=301,L]
#
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /.*index\.html\ HTTP/
RewriteRule ^(.*)index\.html$ http://www.dreamortwosailing.co.uk/$1 [R=301,L]
#

Redirect 301 /index.htm http://www.dreamortwosailing.co.uk/index.php
Redirect 301 /essential_stuff/about_us.php http://www.dreamortwosailing.co.uk/info/us/
```

Comment: What is not working in these rules?

Answer (score 0):

I think your syntax is slightly out on the rules.

Redirect 301 ^/index.htm$ http://www.dreamortwosailing.co.uk/index.php
Redirect 301 ^/essential_stuff/about_us.php$ http://www.dreamortwosailing.co.uk/info/us/